# passing parameters with perl using reflection

Tags: perl, reflection

I have the following Perl module:

```
package module 

sub test1{
  my @data=@_
  print @data;
}
```

When I call this module from a Perl script using:

```
my $test='test1';
my $full_name = "Module::" . $test; 
my @data=(1,2,3)

no strict 'refs'; 
$full_name->(@data);
```

I get no result on stdout but I expected 1,2,3. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Well, for one thing, `@data` is not the same as `$data`...

Comment: You are right but this is not the problem i edited the question again

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Also, why are you turning off `strict refs`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are not setting up your module properly.

Running the following self contained script produces the correct result:

```
{package Module;
    sub test1 {print "test1: @_\n"}
}

my $test = 'test1';
my $full_name = 'Module::'.$test;
my @data = (1, 2, 3);

no strict 'refs';

$full_name->(@data);  # test1: 1 2 3
```

It is hard to tell without seeing exactly what you have, but chances are you have forgotten to include the `package Module;` line at the top of your module.  The package is not implicitly set via the file name, you must declare it at the top of the file.